# Black line above keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout

Somebody know how can avoid this black line above keyboard? It become after my keyboard shows prediction words line.

[Line with help words](http://cs619422.vk.me/v619422622/18fe1/wqO2aSJtjdw.jpg)

[Line after help words](http://cs619422.vk.me/v619422622/18fe8/bxREAq48e0A.jpg)

In my layer I use fragment and I need show line with EditText below. But when user ends typing, he sees black line above keyboard that is not need

Here is my code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"

    android:id="@+id/word_set_fragment_container"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Experimental layer"
         />


</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/border"

    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    >
    <Button

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="⇣"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
    <EditText

        android:inputType="text|textCapSentences"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:hint="@string/hint_new_word"
        android:text=""
        />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2):

In order to avoid black line in your keyboard, you should add `layout_margin="0px"` and `android:padding="0px"` to you keyboard layout xml file

```
<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/keyboard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="0px"
    android:padding="0px"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:keyPreviewLayout ="@layout/preview"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like its the actual android keyboard.. Which isn't something to change.